# Htaccess rule only if last item = number

Tags: .htaccess

i made this rule but its just not working as I need.
How it is working:
If user access /blog it rewrites but files can me reached.
How I expected this works:
If user access /blog or /blog/file.php nothing happens AND
If user access /blog/{NUMBER} it should redirect to /blog/index and give param(number)

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ /blog/index.php?blog=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: Is there a .htaccess inside `/blog/` directory? Or else are there more rules before this rule?

Comment: @starkeen  it is in the root

Comment: @anubhava it is in the root directory

Comment: @anubhava its the only rule

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule in `blog/.htaccess` (create it, if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?blog=$1 [QSA,L]
```